# How to remove extraneous log message from Gradle output

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

When building my Spring Boot project and running the tests from Gradle, there is output from the application shutdown after the tests are complete. Since the output appears to be describing the shutdown of the database connection, I would like to know if there is a way to prevent these messages from being logged.

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

> Task :test 
2018-06-26 11:20:51.220  INFO 37399 --- [       Thread-8] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@2d780437: startup date [Tue Jun 26 11:20:47 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-26 11:20:51.221  INFO 37399 --- [       Thread-6] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@f9ca5ad: startup date [Tue Jun 26 11:20:44 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-26 11:20:51.226  INFO 37399 --- [       Thread-8] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-06-26 11:20:51.227  INFO 37399 --- [       Thread-8] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2018-06-26 11:20:51.375  INFO 37399 --- [       Thread-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-06-26 11:20:51.378  INFO 37399 --- [       Thread-8] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20s
11 actionable tasks: 11 executed
```